# DOMDocument > setAttribute() > bool attribute?

Tags: php, domdocument, dom-manipulation

I try to create a PHP-Class which can compress HTML, so I wanted to replace e.g. required="required" with required. But how can I add an bool attribute via DOMDocument?

Code: https://3v4l.org/Ot9th

```
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->createElement("input");
$newnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("required", '');
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

Result:

```
<input required=""></para>
```

Expected:

```
<input required></para>
```

Answer (score 2):

[PHP's `DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) creates a valid XML structure, and according to both [XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#attdecls) and [XML 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#attdecls) - it's not valid to add empty attributes.

Boolean attributes should have their values the same as the name of the attribute.

> This is valid:

```
<input required="required"></para>
```

> This is **NOT** valid:

```
<input required></para>
```

### update

The `savehtml` function validates content based to `dtd`. According to the [xhtml1.0 dtd](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html), this is the list of attributes that are valid as empty attributes:

```
checked
disabled
readonly
multiple
selected
compact
noshade
declare
ismap
nohref
nowrap
```

Any other attribute must have a value

Comment: `DTD` is what caused it. as long as there is a definition - you can keep with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could solve the problem with usage of random_bytes() and str_replace() ...

Code: https://3v4l.org/WiW8m

```
$rand = md5(random_bytes(16));
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->createElement("input");
$newnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("required", 'delete-this' . $rand);

var_dump(
  str_replace(
    array('="delete-this' . $rand . '"'), 
    array(''), 
    $doc->saveHTML()
  )
);
```